# What Christmas events have happened in space?

Tags: reference-request

Have there been any specifically Christmas related events in space? I assume there's a 'Christmas dinner' on the ISS, but is there anything else?

Comment: I realize that you're asking about human activities in space during the Advent period, but you're not specifically saying it, so I have to mention the [Star of Bethlehem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_of_Bethlehem) :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most famous Christmas-related event was on the [Apollo 8](http://www.space.com/28098-christmas-in-space-apollo8.html) mission. Apollo 8 orbited the Moon on Christmas Eve and into the morning of December 25th.
On Christmas Eve, the crew read [the first 10 verses from Genesis 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_8_Genesis_reading) on TV for what was then the largest TV audience ever. They closed their broadcast with:

> And from the crew of Apollo 8, we close with good night, good luck, a Merry Christmas – and God bless all of you, all of you on the good Earth.